# Siegel's theorem and singular curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, algebraic-curves

I notice that often Siegel's theorem (there are only finitely many integral points on a curve of genus greater than 0) is stated with the requirement that the curve be smooth. Other times the requirement is that the polynomial $F(x,y)$ defining the curve be irreducible. Is either of these really necessary?
If smoothness is a requirement, how could one determine whether an irreducible, singular curve of genus 2 (for example) passes through infinitely many integral points or not?

Comment: I'm not an arithmetic geometer, but here are some remarks. Irreducibility is certainly necessary: otherwise we could take a curve of genus 2 and glue on a line with infinitely many integer points on it. (As for singularity, a curve of high genus with enough nodes will be _rational_, which I think could give a counterexample again, but I have not thought it through.)